# Is there a way to disable the webcam in Mac for development purposes?

Tags: macos, webcam

I'm trying to create a scenario for my software where the web cam is NOT available. Since it is built into my laptop I can't simply unplug it. Is there a way to disable the web cam (like at the hardware level or device driver) so I can simulate a scenario without a web cam for my users who don't have web cams? This is for Mac OSX? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the driver files inaccessible by moving them or changing the permissions. It will disable all webcam's including USB one's as far as i'm aware (assumingly all mac compatible webcam's use the same drivers).

Anyway you can find a automation script here: http://techslaves.org/isight-disabler/